# Bamboo Index Value not between -1 & +1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vegetation-index

I calculated the NDVI (Fig 1) & SMI (Soil Moisture Index i.e. Fig 2) for Landsat-8 with value obtained between -1 and 1.

[image]
Figure: Symbology with NDVI value for Landsat-8 for year 2023

[image]
Figure: Symbology with SI value for Landsat-8 for year 2023

The formula for BI is calculated as:- ***BI= (NDVI-SMI)/(NDVI+SMI)***

The Index value thus produced in float number is:-
[image]

[image]
I got want to know why the index value here is not between -1 and 1 (In contrast, BI value rendering between -3.2 to 7.8).

How can this be solved?

Comment: It looks like your output is a 32 bit signed integer and not 32 bit floating point, not quite sure what caused that as the tool (whichever one it is) has all the other parameters cut off, however it's likely those values are min/max for the pixel type, calculate statistics and they should change to more reasonable values. But first try to calculate as 32 bit floating point or your values will be 0 or 1 with no decimal places.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Could you please explain this more clearly with procedures I need to apply so that my problem can be solved.

Comment: Various data types exist for pixels, it appears you are calculating to an integer data type, as I'm not sure of which tool you are using I can't be more specific. 
As a result the layer is displaying the minimum and maximum possible values for the data type, re-run whatever tool you are using to a floating point pixel type and you might have more success.

Comment: I don't mean float number or other data type. I meant to say that the BI is not rendering result between -1 and +1. Above, BI is produced between -3.2 to 7.8.